# Pyspark: match columns from two different dataframes and add value

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, jupyter-lab

I am trying to compare the values of two columns that exist in different dataframes to create a new dataframe based on the matching of the criteria:

df1=

```
| id |
| -- |
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 3  |
| 4  | 
| 5  |
```

df2 =

```
| id |
| -- |
| 2  |
| 5  |
| 1  |
```

So, I want to add an 'x' in the is_used field when the field of df2 exists in the field of df1, else add 'NA', to generate a result dataframe like this:

df3 =

```
| id | is_used |
| -- | ------- |
| 1  |    X    |
| 2  |    X    |
| 3  |    NA   |
| 4  |    NA   |
| 5  |    X    |
```

I have tried this way, but the selection criteria places an "X" in all columns:

```
df3 = df3.withColumn('is_used', F.when(
    condition = (F.arrays_overlap(F.array(df1.id), F.array(df2.id))) == False,
    value = 'NA'
).otherwise('X'))
```

I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I want to thank the people who contributed their code, it was very useful to understand what was happening.

The problem was that when trying to do df1.id == df2.id Spark was inferring both columns as one because they both had the same name, so the result of all iterations would always be True.

Just rename the fields I wanted to compare and it totally worked for me.

Here is the code:

```
df2 = df2.withColumnRenamed("id", "id1")

df3 = df1.alias("df1").join(df2.alias("df2"),
                            (df1.id == df2.id1), "left")

df3 = df3.withColumn("is_used", F.when(df1.id == df2.id1), 
                     "X").otherwise("NA")

df3 = df3.drop("id1")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `fullouter` join:

```py
df3 = (
    df1.join(df2.alias("df2"), df1.id == df2.id, "fullouter")
    .withColumn(
        "is_used",
        F.when(F.col("df2.id").isNotNull(), F.lit("X")).otherwise(F.lit("NA")),
    )
    .drop(F.col("df2.id"))
    .orderBy(F.col("id"))
)
```

Result:

```
+---+-------+                                                                   
|id |is_used|
+---+-------+
|1  |X      |
|2  |X      |
|3  |NA     |
|4  |NA     |
|5  |X      |
+---+-------+
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your code but I can't solve my problem, anyway thank you very much.
Solve my problem in a way much like yours

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, it would give you a similar result and you can make the rest of the changes:

```py
df3 = df1.alias("df1").\
    join(df2.alias("df2"), (df1.id==df2.id), how='left').\
    withColumn('is_true', F.when(df1.id == df2.id,F.lit("X")).otherwise(F.lit("NA"))).\ 
    select("df1.*","is_true")

df3.show()
```

Comment: I have tried your code, it works but I still have the same problem, the column ignores the match criteria and adds an X in all rows. I have verified that this is correct, but no, my df1 contains 261 records, my df2 contains 152, so I should see only 152 "X", but I see the whole column filled with "X" :(